# SZ_GetSpace overflow in Paintball 2

Tags: mods, quake-2

When I try to start a match in [Digital Paint: Paintball 2](http://www.digitalpaint.org) I get a huge amount of error messages after I click 'Start Game'.
The error message is:

`SZ_GetSpace: overflow`
`WARNING: msg overflowed for x3m157`

(x3m157 is my username). Any idea what is causing this? The map I'm trying to load is `pball_shred`. Thanks!

EDIT: After I do this, if I press ESC to get back to the main menu and click 'Join Game', the game I tried to start shows up on the list, but when I try to join, I get the same error messages

EDIT #2: This doesn't change if I change the map that I am trying to have the match on.
The elim time does not affect anything either. I have started a bounty in the hope of getting an answer to this annoying problem. (if you get the Tumbleweed badge, you know something's wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I posted my question on the DigitalPaint forum and I got an answer (from jitspoe himself :)
[Here](http://dplogin.com/forums/index.php?topic=22666.new) is a link to the post on DigitalPaint.

The problem was I was trying to load to many grenades. I changed the number of grens and it worked.